# How to add to an array of objects, an object that is inherited? (Swift, XCode)

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, inheritance, constructor

```
var allCards = [CCard]
var cardsMade = 0
```

^^ is outside of my view controller class as to make it global and accessible in all other view controller files.

in another view controller i have

```
@IBAction func saveInfo(sender: UIButton) {
    let a = CCreature(n: cName!, e: cExpansion, ec: cEnergy!, tc: cTurnCount!,
        ef: cEffect!, at: cStrength!, ht:cHealth!, sp: cSpeed!, sb: false)
    allCards.append(a)
    cardsMade++}
```

so when the saveInfo button is pressed, i put all the information the user has typed (which were in UITextFields, and then saved into the corresponding vairables cEnergy etc..) into a subclass of CCard called CCreature, with all of the information. After I create the instance of the class, i am trying to store in the array allCards. I am getting an error on the line:

```
var allCards = [CCard]
```

**Expected member name or constructor call after type name**

And in the line where a is appended to the array i am getting this error:

**Cannot convert value of type 'CCreature' to expected argument type 'inout Array   < CCard >'**

I was also getting this error message before, when my program was compiling:

**fatal error: Array index out of range**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As you have it `[CCard]` is a type declaration, you could use it as:

```
var allCards : [CCard]
```

but, that won't actually initialize allCards to be useful, alternatively, you could actually create the array and initialize it using:

```
var allCards = [CCard]()
```

Where you're using the default array constructor

It's not the entirety of your example, because you didn't include a lot of the pieces, but stripped down to show usage, would be:

```
var allCards = [CCard]()

func saveInfo() {
    let a = CCreature()
    allCards.append(a)
}
```